# Is it possible to calculate sphere surface area with circles?

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

Imagine cutting a sphere into circles(the distance between the two circles is almost zero).
Then is it correct to say that the sum of the circumference of all the circles is the surface area of the sphere? (Please describe why not)

$S_{sphere}=2\sum_{h=0}^{r}{2\sqrt{r^2-h^2}\pi}$      
(Where $\sqrt{r^2-h^2}$ is radius in each circle with distance $h$ to center, Also multiplied by 2 because it's sum of circles in semisphere)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This does not work because in fact you decompose the sphere in cylindrical surfaces, which does not account for the local slope. Conical slices would work.

Comment: @BobbyLaspy No I don't! Imagine we make a sphere with circles(We put them on top of each other and then result is a great sphere with correct shape), So if we calculate circumference of all circles, we get sphere surface area.

Comment: The area or figure is not the sum of length of parts of lines that are inside of figure except the case when the width of parts cut by lines will be equal. The same for sphere and circles. You need to place circles in such way that thickness of sphere area parts (bands) will be equal. Of course, you need also to make this thickness tending to zero.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Thank you, Then if thickness become zero, will this work?

Comment: Why do you ask the question if you know the [wrong] answer ?

Comment: By the way, congrats, you found the value of the area to be $\pi^2r^2$.

Comment: @BobbyLaspy Thank you, yes I found that:) (but i think its $\pi^2r$

Comment: Now you are entitled to fix the big mistake in the Wikipedia entry: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere#Surface_area

Comment: @BobbyLaspy OK, I will 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sphere $$x^2+y^2+z^2=r^2$$

Circle $$x^2+y^2=r^2-h_1^2,\;z=h_1$$

Next circle $$x^2+y^2=r^2-h_2^2,\;z=h_2$$

Thickness of sphere area bands located between circles $$w=\sqrt{(h_2-h_1)^2+(\sqrt{r^2-h_1^2}-\sqrt{r^2-h_2^2})^2}=\sqrt{2r^2-2h_1h_2-2\sqrt{(r^2-h_1^2)(r^2-h_2^2)}}$$

$$h_2=h_1+\Delta h, \Delta h \ll h_1 \Rightarrow w=\frac{r}{\sqrt{r^2-h_1^2}}\Delta h+O(\Delta h)^2$$

When $w\to 0$: $\Delta h \to \frac{w}{r} \sqrt{r^2-h_1^2}$

So you need to take $h$ in such way that difference of to subsequent $h$ values is  $\frac{w}{r} \sqrt{r^2-h^2}$ with some small $w$ tending to zero.

Comment: Thank you:))) but I can't understand what's $w$

Comment: What is the final result ?

Comment: I wrote $h$ as coefficient of $r$(something like($(nr)^2$) and then change $\sum$ to $2\int_{0}^{1}2\pi \sqrt{r^2-n^2r^2}$ and final is $\pi^2 r$

Comment: @ArmanAhmadi: I was asking Ivan. But don't you worry that $4\pi r^2=\pi^2r$ ???

Answer (score 0):

Distance between intersecting planes is very small, you wish to say?

The circumference is that of a *polygon*. So you get a smaller boundary length.

However the disc volumes sum up correctly.

Comment: Yes, Distance between planes is very small(Something like 0). Do you mean this work for sphere volume?

Comment: Yes it does  because the meridian has not been compromised to be straight. $ V= \int \pi r^2 dz$

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you take $\theta$ to be the angle between $r$ and the north pole then your $h$ is just $r\sin{\theta}$ and at each value of theta the surface area of the ribbon is $$rd\theta(2\pi r\sin{\theta})=2\pi r^2\sin{\theta}d\theta$$

The $rd\theta$ term is the arc length corresponding to the width of the ribbon and $2\pi r\sin{\theta}$ is its circumference.

You end up with the integral $$2\pi r^2\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin{\theta}d\theta=4\pi r^2$$

Comment: Thanks for your professional and nice answer